# PrimeNg : Error lines are showing in all html files for prime ng elements

Tags: angular, primeng

The prime ng elements are working fine but the red error lines still showing for each and every html pages.

Please find attached screenshot for the reference.

[image]

Here are the package details :

primeNG : 13.4.1
Angular : 13.3.4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you dont have **CardModule** in **app.module.ts** imports.

Comment: I just hover the p-card, so its showing like that otherwise for every prime element, its showing that so and so module is not found error. But I have added all the required modules and its working fine in the browser as expected. I am trying to avoid those red lines.

Comment: then maybe issue with the linter, have you set up some already?